# Two NSDates created next to each other do not compare equal

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, switch-statement, nsdate

This code, comparing two `NSDate`s created one after the other, does not enter the `.OrderedSame` case as I would expect.

```
import UIKit

let chosenDate = NSDate()

let currentDate = NSDate()

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

let day = formatter.stringFromDate(chosenDate)

var result = String()

switch chosenDate.compare(currentDate) {

case .OrderedSame:
    result = "Today is a \(day)"
    break
case .OrderedAscending:
    result = "That was a \(day)"
    break
case .OrderedDescending:
    result = "That will be a \(day)"
    break
}

print(result)
```

Whenever I run this (in a playground or [I pulled this into a playground from my project file to test stuff] in the Simulator) it gives me "That **was** a (insert day here) instead of "**Today** is a (insert day here). Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of `chosenDate` and `currentDate` are not the same. If you print the values of the dates, you will see that they are different, likely by a few milliseconds.

If you want to check if the *days* are the same, you need to try the `NSCalendar` method [compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:)

You can use `NSCalendarUnitDay` to compare if the dates are on the same day.

Comment: Just *printing* the dates will not show the difference, as the default description method does not include fractional seconds. But good advice about `compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:`!

Answer (score 3):

The dates are *not* the same, and you can verify that easily with

```
let chosenDate = NSDate()
let currentDate = NSDate()

print(chosenDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
print(currentDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
print(currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(chosenDate))
```

Sample output:

```
483241075.692769
483241075.692773
3.99351119995117e-06
```

`NSDate` represents a point in time, stored as a `NSTimeInterval`
(aka `Double`) with the time in seconds since  1 January 2001.
This time span includes *fractional seconds*.